# Non-Grid Based Movement in a Tile Map

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, movement

I'm making a dungeon game, and I'm doing input. When I move left or down until the code stops the player, I can no longer move any way except opposite the way I moved. Let's say I moved all the way left. The `canmovethere()` method stops the player from moving anymore. The player is now "stuck" in the wall; I can't move it up or down, only right. This also happens for moving down, but not up or right.

Here's the code:

```
public class PlayerInputProcessor {
   private PlayerCharacter player;
   private Dungeon dungeon;

   private final int NORTH = 0, SOUTH = 1, WEST = 2, EAST = 3;

   public PlayerInputProcessor(PlayerCharacter player, Dungeon dungeon) {
   this.player = player;
      this.dungeon = dungeon;
   }

   public void HandleInput() {
      if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
         if(canmovethere(player.getGridPos(), NORTH)) {
            player.setVectorPosY(player.getVectorPosY() + 3);
         }
      }
      if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) {
         if(canmovethere(player.getGridPos(), SOUTH)) {
            player.setVectorPosY(player.getVectorPosY() - 3);
         }
      }
      if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) {
         if(canmovethere(player.getGridPos(), EAST)) {
            player.setVectorPosX(player.getVectorPosX() + 3);
         }
      }
      if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {
         if(canmovethere(player.getGridPos(), WEST)) {
            player.setVectorPosX(player.getVectorPosX() - 3);
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Grid Pos " + player.getGridPos());

      player.setGridPos(new GridPoint2((int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(),
         (int) player.getVectorPosY() / player.getHight()));

      if(dungeon.getTile(player.getGridPos()) instanceof FloorTile) {
         System.out.println("On A Floor Tile");
      }
   }

   private Boolean canmovethere(GridPoint2 newpos, int die) {
      GridPoint2 nextpos = new GridPoint2();

      if(die == NORTH) {
         nextpos.x = newpos.x;
         nextpos.y = (newpos.y + 1);
         if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      if(die == SOUTH) {
         nextpos.x = newpos.x;
         nextpos.y = (newpos.y);
         if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      if(die == EAST) {
         nextpos.x = newpos.x + 1;
         nextpos.y = newpos.y;
            if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
               return true;
            }
      }
      if(die == WEST) {
         nextpos.x = (newpos.x + player.getWidth() / player.getWidth()) - 1;
         nextpos.y = newpos.y;
         if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the `(newpos.x + player.getWidth() / player.getWidth()) - 1;` line? Based on the order of operations this equals to `newpos.x + 1 - 1` which equals `newpos.x`

Comment: That was me trying anything that might work i did not see it until you said something. i see how silly that was now.

Comment: I think the problem is with the coordinates. The "SOUTH" part of `canmovethere` should check the coordinates `(newpos.x, newpos.y - 1)` and "WEST" should check `(newpos.x - 1, newpos.y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Balint for the idea

I needed to check where the player was going to be not the tile in front of it.

so i changed `if(canmovethere(player.getGridPos(), WEST))`  too
`if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) (player.getVectorPosX() - 3) / 64, (int)player.getVectorPosY() / 64), WEST))`

Again I would not have fixed my problem if not for @Balint's comments.

Answer (score 1):

When you checking if you can move onto another tile, you are sometimes just giving the player's current location. Balint point out one, and the other is when you go try to go south.

Change `nextpos.y = (newpos.y);` to `nextpos.y = newpos.y - 1;` and change `nextpos.x = (newpos.x + player.getWidth() / player.getWidth()) - 1;` to `nextpos.x = newpos.x - 1;`. I'm not sure why it was block disabling movement when looking at the player's position (Maybe something in the `isPassable()` method?), but if it works with two directions, this should let it work for the other two.

Comment: This did not work. It did in fact let me "slide" up and down the (when i move left) but the player stoped one tile before the wall.

Comment: @ThePumkinMelon That's because you check for one tile in front of the player. Try constructing the new vector position of the player (add 3 to the position), then get the grid positions of that and if the grid containing that position is passable, set the player's position to the new vector position

Comment: @Balint if you make a answer i will vote you because you helped me solve my problem.

Comment: @ThePumkinMelon I'm already over my rep cap for today, I'll let tyjkenn post it